# Embed Windows XP Theme in C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp, themes

I have a legacy C# Windows Forms application with the layout designed on the Windows XP default theme.
Due to the need to distribute it as a Citrix application, the application now looks like as a Classic Theme application, because Citrix discourages the use of the Theme system service.

So, now I don't want to depend anymore on the Themes system service, but keep the Windows XP default Theme design, even on Windows 7 computers (Citrix server is a Windows 2008 R2 computer).

Is there a way to accomplish this, embedding the Windows XP default theme DLLs into my application?

Comment: The look & feel is driven through the common controls library which respects the theming service, so unless you move to using a simulation of the theme, I don't think it's going to work

Comment: Are the Theming service DLLs referenceable as other DLLs in a VS project? If so I imagine they use some SW artifact to control how to draw controls... Maybe I can extend or decorate common controls to override the use of theming and let them use the same API through a reference to the themes DLL which then I can distribute with the application. Senseless?

Comment: Set classic theme on the server and you're good to go. WinForms UI not complying to system's settings (as in a classic theme-looking application in a Aero environment) will generally be considered FUBAR.