# Can the Windows 7 visual style be used in Windows 10?

Tags: winforms

I like the Windows 7 visual style very much:

[image]

A button looks like this on Windows 10:

[image]

Is there a way to force the Windows 7 style with WinForms on a higher platform?

Thank you!

Comment: It's called "Aero."  Have a look here: https://github.com/LorenzCK/WindowsFormsAero

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you, but I was hoping to be able to use something maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft does not maintain an Aero/Winforms combination.

Comment: [A few years ago ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14213538/3110834)